# Change UUID value of beacon with AltBeacon SDK?

Tags: android, uuid, altbeacon, beacon

I need to create app on android for modify UUID of beacon. I have been looking for some informations on Altbeacons docs but I haven't found anything.

Also I 'asked' to google for tutorials, samples, or anything, and nothing.

Please, can someone tell me something about this? Classes, samples, tutorials, whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AltBeacon project does not provide any mechanism for configuring beacons.  It is an open source standard for the format a beacon transmits.

Similarly, the Android Beacon Library does not provide any beacon configuration SDK.

Because there is no standard way of configuring beacons, the mechansim is different for every beacon vendor.  You must request an SDK or configuration app from whoever manufactured your beacon.